# Ordering bars in dodged ggplot geom_bar based on group or subgroup maximum

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, ranking, geom-bar

##### The problem

I have a grouped bar plot and I would like to order the groups according the the maximum value of one subgroup. I have read many similar questions, but most of them deal with ordering at the group level, not the subgroup level. Below is an example to see what I mean.

##### Reprex

Here is some made up data about seven people and their music preferences.

```
set.seed(3)
df <- data.frame(person = c("John", "Sarah", "Alex", "Kate", "Oliver", "Emily", "Daniel"),
                 music_genre = rep(c("pop", "classical", "rap"), each = 7),
                 listens = sample(40:90, size = 21, replace = TRUE))
```

In terms of packages, I am using `library(tidyverse)`. Here is a simple bar plot without any ordering.

```
ggplot(data=df) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=person,
               y=listens,
               fill=music_genre),
           stat="identity",
           position="dodge")
```

[image]

##### What  I tried

My goal would be to create a bar plot that orders the `persons` by the number of `listens` of a particular `music_genre` while keeping the bars of all music genres in the plot.

What I know how to do is ordering `persons` by the number of `listens` across all values of `music_genre`. This isn't what I want however. (As an aside, notice how the classical music disappears in the plot below because it has the same value as rap. If you know how to solve this I'd be curious to know.

```
ggplot(data=df) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=reorder(person, listens, max),
               y=listens,
               fill=music_genre,
               group=position),
           stat="identity",
           position="dodge")
```

[image]

Another thing that is discussed in a lot of posts but that does not address my issue is how to sort subgroups, i.e. how to sort within `persons`. For this, we can add a new variable to the df and then group by this variable. Compared to the code before, this is done with an extra line that contains a a `mutate()` call.

```
set.seed(3)
df <- data.frame(person = c("John", "Sarah", "Alex", "Kate", "Oliver", "Emily", "Daniel"),
                 music_genre = rep(c("pop", "classical", "rap"), each = 7),
                 listens = sample(40:90, size = 21, replace = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(position = rank(-listens))
```

Now the subgroups can be sorted like so. (Notice again how the classical category disappears for Daniel.)

```
ggplot(data=df) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=person,
               y=listens,
               fill=music_genre,
               group=position),
           stat="identity",
           position="dodge")
```

[image]

Ordering at group level and sorting at subgroup level can also be combined.

```
ggplot(data=df) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=reorder(person, listens, max),
               y=listens,
               fill=music_genre,
               group=position),
           stat="identity",
           position="dodge")
```

[image]

Once again this does not address my issue. I'm only mentioning this to make my question clearer and to show what  I understand and what I don't.

##### TL;DR

To reiterate, how can I get a plot that sorts the x-axis (persons) according the max number of the y-axis value (listens) of a particular group (music_genre)?

Comment: "how can I get a plot that sorts the x-axis (persons) according the max number of the y-axis value (listens) of a particular group (music_genre)?" Can you simply state your goal again. Is your last plot (besides not having classical for Daniel) the desired output?

Comment: Sorry, my question is a bit complicated, I tried my best to be clear. I want to have the person who listens to, e.g., most rap music to the right, the person in second place to the left etc. The last above plot _incidentally_ happens to almost achieve this for classical music. But this is a pure coincident. Maybe I could change the data to avoid such confusion. Also Daniel actually listens to more classical than Kate, so it's not 100% correct anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = person, names_from = music_genre, values_from = listens) %>% 
  mutate(pos_id = rank(pop)) %>% ## genre that subgroups will be ordered based on
  pivot_longer(-c(person, pos_id), names_to = "music_genre", values_to = "listens") %>% 
  group_by(person) %>% 
  mutate(position = rank(-listens)) %>% 
 ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x=reorder(person, pos_id, max),
               y=listens,
               fill=music_genre,
               group=position), ## use music_genre if you don't want to order subgroups
           stat="identity",
           position="dodge") +
  xlab("person")
```

[image]

##### Data:

```
structure(list(person = c("John", "Sarah", "Alex", "Kate", "Oliver", 
                           "Emily", "Daniel", "John", "Sarah", "Alex", 
                            "Kate", "Oliver", "Emily", "Daniel", "John", 
                            "Sarah", "Alex", "Kate", "Oliver", "Emily", "Daniel"), 
                music_genre = c("pop", "pop", "pop", "pop", "pop", "pop", "pop", 
                                "classical", "classical", "classical", "classical", 
                                "classical", "classical", "classical", "rap", "rap", 
                                "rap", "rap", "rap", "rap", "rap"), 
                listens = c(44L, 51L, 78L, 75L, 79L, 82L, 70L, 47L, 59L, 49L, 79L, 
                            87L, 79L, 47L, 76L, 41L, 68L, 83L, 84L, 44L, 79L)), 
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -21L))
```

Comment: This does not solve my problem, it is the exact same code as a chunk in the "What I tried" section of my post... To rephrase, what I want to have is the persons sorted from right to left according to the maximum value of "rap", "classical" or "pop". In your example using "pop" for ranking, want Emily to the right (highest `listens` for pop), next Oliver (second highest `listens` for pop), next Alex (third highest `listens` for pop) etc.

Comment: It's not the exact same code. See the use of `group_by`. But I understand your problem. For future reference, try to be specific in your example. No need to go above and beyond. It's good that you have a complete and verifiable example, but don't forget that it should be minimal as well.

Answer (score 0):

After some more tinkering, I found a way to make it happen.

The desired result can be achieved by coding the persons (i.e., the categorical variable on the x-axis) as a factor, then ordering the factor levels by the a ranked subset of the original data containing only the ranking category of interest (e.g., "pop").

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    person = factor(
      person,
      levels = df %>% 
        filter(music_genre=="pop") %>% 
        arrange(listens) %>% 
        pull(person),
      ordered= T))
```

Plotting a grouped bar plot achieves what we want: The persons are sorted from highest to lowest value for "pop".

```
ggplot(data=df) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=person,
               y=listens,
               fill=music_genre),
           stat="identity",
           position="dodge")
```

[image]

If anyone has found a smarter way to do this, especially one that works inside the `ggplot()` call, I'd curious to hear it.